# Error "Could not find any index named [IX_MyIndex]" upon creating it

Tags: sql-server

I came before this very weird error:

> Msg 7999, Level 16, State 9, Line 12
>   Could not find any index named 'IX_MyIndex' for table 'dbo.MyTable'.

When running the script to create it!!

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyIndex] ON [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [Field1]
    ,[Field2]
    ) INCLUDE (
    Fields3
    ,Fields4
    ,Fields5
    )
    WITH (
         MAXDOP = 4
         ,DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE
         ,DROP_EXISTING = ON
        )
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "DROP_EXISTING=ON" might give a clue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the last line and execute it.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyIndex] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
([Field1],[Field2]) 
INCLUDE (Fields3, Fields4, Fields5)
```

It is trying to search index with name - `IX_MyIndex` which is not available. But after creating an index of name `IX_MyIndex` you can run the same query.

Comment: Right! thank you So much! Actually it is not all of the last line's fault, it is the DROP_EXISTING=ON option problem!

Answer (score 18):

With the help of Suraj's answer I found that the problem was the option:

```
DROP_EXISTING=ON
```

It does not work as I suspected (drop the index IF exists), instead it tries to find it and drop it!

Removing it did the trick!

Comment: Yes it tries to search index with name - IX_MyIndex which is not available. But after creating index of name IX_MyIndex you can run the same query.

Comment: Far better to mark Suraj's response as the answer than to post your own. Because that is how SO works. People post questions, people reply with potential answers, question poser marks the correct answer.